# How do i correctly parse my csv file using DOM?

Tags: java, csv

I have managed to get the file to output the XML. But for some reason when an element does not exist in the parentLocalityName only the end tag appears like this, as you can see only the end tag appears. How do i change amend my code so that the whole tag appears but nothing be inside it?

```
-<BusStopDetails>

<AtcoCode>0800COC31523</AtcoCode>

<CommonName>Bus Station</CommonName>

<LocalityName>Newquay</LocalityName>

<ParentLocalityName/>

<Latitude>50.4130339395</Latitude>

<Longitude>-5.0856695446</Longitude>

</BusStopDetails>
```

This is my Java program which converts the file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import java.io.File;

public class CSV2XML {

    // Protected Properties
    protected DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = null;
    protected DocumentBuilder domBuilder = null;

    // CTOR
    public CSV2XML() {
        try {
            domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        } catch (FactoryConfigurationError exp) {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException exp) {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            System.err.println(exp.toString());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, TransformerException {
        ArrayList<String> busStopInfo = new ArrayList<String>(7);
        // An array list has been used to store the elements from the csv file. They are stored as strings.
        try {

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\liaml\\OneDrive\\Documents\\CSCU9T4 XML assignment\\lrl00002\\stops.csv");
            BufferedReader readFile = null;

            DocumentBuilderFactory df = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db;

            db = df.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = db.newDocument();

            // Root element
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("BusStops"); // root element "Busstops created"

            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            readFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            int line = 0; // Represent the lines in the file, starts at the 0th,
                            // increments after every line has been tokenised
                            // for elements line of the file

            String information = null;
            while ((information = readFile.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] tokens = information.split(","); // removes comma until there is no more commas

                String[] row = information.split(","); // store elements after the command, length 6 to store headers



                if (line == 0) {
                    for (String column : row) {
                        busStopInfo.add(column); // This will add column headers from rowValues to busStopInfo ArrayList

                    }
                } else {
                    Element childElement = doc.createElement("BusStopDetails"); // creates child element details

                    rootElement.appendChild(childElement);
                    for (int column = 0; column < busStopInfo.size(); column++) {

                        String header = busStopInfo.get(column);
                        String value = null;

                        if (column < row.length) {
                            value = row[column];
                        } else {
                            value = " ";
                        }

                        Element current = doc.createElement(header); // creates element of current header

                        current.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value)); // creates placement for value

                        childElement.appendChild(current); // adds current value of the header into child element details


                        // Save the document to the disk file
                        TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                        Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
                        aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                        aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                        aTransformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
                        Source src = new DOMSource(doc);
                        information = ("C:\\Users\\liaml\\OneDrive\\Documents\\CSCU9T4 XML assignment\\lrl00002\\stops.xml");
                        Result dest = new StreamResult(new File(information));
                        aTransformer.transform(src, dest);


                        if (line >= 0) {
                            System.out.println("CSV File has been successfully converted to XML File & Stored in Zip Folder "
                                    + "(" + String.valueOf(line) + " row)");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(
                                    "Error while converting input CSV File " + args[0] + " to output XML File " + args[1] + " ");
                        }

                    }
                }
                line++;
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`<ParentLocalityName/>` is an *empty* tag.
`</ParentLocalityName>` is a *end* tag.
Not the same thing.

An empty tag ([see XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#d0e2480)) is shorthand for a start tag and an end tag.

```
<ParentLocalityName></ParentLocalityName>
<ParentLocalityName/>
```

The above two lines mean exactly the same thing, and cannot be distinguished once parsed.

BTW: Your title is bogus: You cannot *parse* a CSV file *using* DOM.
You are reading a CSV file and *writing* XML using DOM.